# get values from string

Tags: c#, string

in my variable:

```
string selectedObjects;
```

i have one long value like:

```
"123;132;213;231;"
```

i want to get 4 times values as: `"123;" , "132;" , "213;" and "231;".`

i tryed with foreach as:

```
public ActionResult ShowHistory(string selectedObjects)
    {
        foreach (string item in selectedObjects)
        {
            item = selectedObjects.Split(';');
        }
```

but it doesnt work. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is incorrect. Split returnes an array through which you should than iterate, using foreach if that's your choice. So:

```
foreach (string item in selectedObjects.Split(';'))
{
    // do whatever you want with the items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("123;132;213;231;", @"\d+;"))
    string value = m.Value; //Do something worthwhile with the value.
```

All of the other answers are wrong or overkill - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You need a double backslash \\ on that d+ and I don't think he wan't the semicolons.

Comment: Right, I updated my answer. And according to the question the expected output is "123;" , "132;" , "213;" and "231;" - including the semi-colon. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, yes the @ will also do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult ShowHistory(string selectedObjects)
{
    foreach (string tempItem in selectedObjects.Split(new []{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        string item = tempItem + ";"; // Add back on the ; character
    }
    // .. do something
```

The [RemoveEmptyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) is required, otherwise, you'll get an empty string at the end (because your input string ends with ";").  Also, string.Split does not preserve the separator char, so you need to add it back in if you want it (hence the `tempItem`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the semi-colon again after splitting.

```
public ActionResult ShowHistory(string selectedObjects)
{
    var items = selectedObjects.Split(';')
                               .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
                               .Select(i => i + ";");
    ...
}
```

Or (if you can guarantee that exact format)

```
public ActionResult ShowHistory(string selectedObjects)
{
    var items = selectedObjects.TrimEnd(';')
                               .Split(';')
                               .Select(i => i + ";");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split returns an array of `string`.

```
string selectedObjects = ...;

foreach (string item in selectedObjects.Split(';'))
{
   // do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(string item in selectedObjects.Split(new [] {';'}, 
                                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                      .Select( x=> x+";"))
{
   //process item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split method returns array of string, try somehting like this

```
string selectedObjects = "123;132;213;231;";
string[] s = selectedObjects.Split(';');

foreach (string item in s )
{
    Console.Writeline(item.ToString());
}
```